# How to link Essbase in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, essbase

I need to join SQL Server data with some data from Essbase cube. Result will be in SQL Server. Is it possible to create linked essbase cubu in SQL Server 2014 to query data? Or any other way how to get data physically from essbase to SQL Server not using export files? Something like direct connect.

Thanks,

Comment: Ever heard of [`SSIS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services) ?

Comment: Yes, I did. But connector for Essbase is avaiable only in SSRS and not in SSIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't any native ways to implement what your want. Setting this up will typically require some sort of automation to extract the data in the cube to a CSV file, then loading that data using SSIS or your preferred ETL tool. The automation to extract data will frequently be a combination of batch file, MaxL and report script or a calc script with a data export command.